# Understanding ST's quantification and phantom type

Tags: haskell, quickcheck, forall, phantom-types, rank-n-types

I am trying to write monadic test code using [`Test.QuickCheck.Monadic`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.14.2/docs/Test-QuickCheck-Monadic.html).

The module provides a harness

```hs
monadicST :: Testable a => (forall s. PropertyM (ST s) a) -> Property
```

to execute `ST`-based tests, and a function

```
run :: Monad m => m a -> PropertyM m a
```

to lift any action into a test monad.

In my code I have a polymorphic monadic action:

```hs
act :: Monad m => a -> m ()
act = undefined
```

The following function

```hs
st :: a -> Property
st = monadicST . run . act
```

fails to compile:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘PropertyM m0 ()’
                 with ‘forall s. PropertyM (ST s) a0’
  Expected type: PropertyM m0 () -> Property
    Actual type: (forall s. PropertyM (ST s) a0) -> Property
• In the first argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘monadicST’
  In the expression: monadicST . run . act
  In an equation for ‘st’: st = monadicST . run . act
```

but this one

```hs
st' :: a -> Property
st' a = monadicST $ run $ act a
```

compiles without a problem.

Can anyone explain?